# how to put original badges on product image in magento?

Tags: php, magento

i have one product which has two images.

```
      (1)image-1(originle image)

      (2)image-2
```

now images are showing in product details page **but now i want customize that i want to write on image-1 put some text like original image**

i have tried like **skin_url**, **getMediaGalleryImages()**

```
     echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image');

    echo $_product->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('label', 'LABEL_NAME');
```

but not working

i want to how to get first image name of product??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
echo $_product->getImageUrl();
```

If you need the Image-Name, you have many possibilties, like explode or regex ...

__
Edit:
You can try your method, too, just add a "->getUrl();"

```
$_product->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('label', 'LABEL_NAME')->getUrl();
```

If this is also "not working", maybe you could give us a little hint, what "not working" actually means, is there an error or a result, which you don't want ...

Thanks!

Comment: hello pls check now question

Comment: Is this not working?
`$_product->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('label', 'LABEL_NAME')->getUrl();`
Did you get the image name?

What is "image-name" for you?
Something like this: image123.jpg?

If you get the URL, like: www.page.com/img/image123.jpg, you could explode it with php and then you will have the image-name:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: but its not give me image name and how can i get that the first product image?

Comment: What does it give you, send an example!

Comment: its give nothing its blank